# matching two dataframe index by month

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, indexing

I have two dataframe, one in weekly frequency and one in monthly frequency:

```
df_week:
               A   B
2012-01-02    0.1 0.2
2012-01-09    0.4 0.3
2012-01-16    0.4 0.4
2012-01-23    0.3 0.3
2012-01-30    0.2 0.4
2012-02-06    0.1 0.5
```

Monthly data (empty):

```
df_monthly
              A   
2012-01-31   NaN 
2012-02-29   NaN 
2012-03-31   NaN
```

What I want to do is to find out the last week in each month (for example, 2012-01-30 for January 2012), and then look at 52 weeks before the date to regress A over B, and record the entry as df_monthly.loc['2012-01-31', 'A']. What I have so far is loop over df_week:

```
for i in range(52, len(df_week)-1): 
    if df_week.index[i].month ~= df_week.index[i+1].month: #find out last week of the month
        temp = df_week.iloc[i-52, :]
        regress temp.A on temp.B
```

I now have the coefficient, sm.OLS.params[1]. But I don't know how to map it to the df_monthly data in an easy way. Theoretically, I need to find index j at df_month where:

```
 df_month.index[j].month = df_week.index[i].month
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one entry in `df_month` you want to use (how I understand the question) than you can create boolean mask on the index to return the correct row of `df_month`.

Both indexes need to be pandas datetime datatype so you may access `.month`

If you have your regression coefficient `C` and index  `i` of `df_week` you can do something like

```
mask = (df_month.index.month == df_week.iloc[i].name.month)
df_month.loc[mask, 'A'] = C
# you can access row with just df_month[mask] also
```

Comment: sorry i didn't mention that the data span more than 1 year of data. so i think the mask will pick up multiple values. Is there a year_month version of "df_month.index.month", i.e. returning both year and month of the index?

Comment: update(i didnt use edit so that it can be referenced for people with similar issues): i used a "&": mask = (df_month.index.month == df_week.iloc[i].name.month) & (df_month.index.year == df_week.iloc[i].name.year)  I think it works (it's running without error now)